# Setting CronTrigger start and end times with minutes

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to specify start and end time for CronTrigger with minutes also?
For instance:
`"0/5 * 12-18 * * ?"` would fire every 5 seconds from 12:00 to 18:00. However, I want to set up trigger which would start at 12:30, ends at 18:55 everyday and fires every 20 minutes. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `DailyTimeIntervalTrigger` as a scheduler and create two jobs.

[JavaDoc DailyTimeIntervaltrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.html)